# using dummify with the dummies datapack in R

Tags: r, regression

We want to perform a regression modelof the following dataset:

[image: the dataset]

There are 3 different variables, all factors. For the regression model we want to dummify the variable: container_ids using the dummies package in R

Once that variable is dummified we want to combine the variables "datum" and "fill_level" with the different dummy variables so we can perform our regression model

the problem we have:
we can create dummy data of container_ids in a separate matrix but not in a dataframe. If we want to combine this matrix with the two variables datum and fill_level it doesn't show what we want it to show.

It shows this:
[image: what is shows]

but it needs to add all the different container_ids dummy data

can someone please help us out, would be very nice!

the code we used:

```
#containerids dummies
    library(dummies)
    str(container_group)

#creating a matrix with all the dummy data
dummy_container_ids <- dummy(container_group$container_ids, sep="_")


#this doesn't work
containers_dummy <- dummy.data.frame(container_group,sep="_")

#combine the data 
#but it only adds one column instead of the multiple dummy data we want to add
combined_data <- cbind(container_group[c(1,3)], dummy_container_ids)
```

the output i get when: dput(head(container_group, 20))

```
structure(list(datum = structure(1:20, .Label = c("2017-01-02", 
"2017-01-04", "2017-01-05", "2017-01-09", "2017-01-12", "2017-01-16", 
"2017-01-19", "2017-01-21", "2017-01-23", "2017-01-26", "2017-01-28", 
"2017-01-30", "2017-02-02", "2017-02-03", "2017-02-06", "2017-02-10", 
"2017-02-13", "2017-02-18", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-23", "2017-02-25", 
"2017-02-27", "2017-03-03", "2017-03-06", "2017-03-13", "2017-03-15", 
"2017-03-17", "2017-03-20", "2017-03-21", "2017-03-27", "2017-03-31", 
"2017-04-03", "2017-04-05", "2017-04-07", "2017-04-10", "2017-04-15", 
"2017-04-16", "2017-04-20", "2017-04-24", "2017-04-25", "2017-04-28", 
"2017-05-01", "2017-05-06", "2017-05-08", "2017-05-11", "2017-05-13", 
"2017-05-15", "2017-05-17", "2017-05-19", "2017-05-22", "2017-05-26", 
"2017-05-31", "2017-06-03", "2017-06-06", "2017-06-08", "2017-06-13", 
"2017-06-23", "2017-06-26", "2017-07-04", "2017-07-11", "2017-07-12", 
"2017-07-15", "2017-07-17", "2017-07-19", "2017-07-28", "2017-07-31", 
"2017-08-03", "2017-08-05", "2017-08-07", "2017-08-10", "2017-08-12", 
"2017-08-15", "2017-08-16", "2017-08-18", "2017-08-21", "2017-08-24", 
"2017-08-25", "2017-08-29", "2017-09-02", "2017-09-05", "2017-09-07", 
"2017-09-12", "2017-09-13", "2017-09-16", "2017-09-18", "2017-09-25", 
"2017-10-06", "2017-10-09", "2017-10-11", "2017-10-13", "2017-10-16", 
"2017-10-17", "2017-10-20", "2017-10-23", "2017-10-25", "2017-10-27", 
"2017-11-02", "2017-11-06", "2017-11-09", "2017-11-11", "2017-11-13", 
"2017-11-15", "2017-11-20", "2017-11-24", "2017-11-27", "2017-11-28", 
"2017-12-07", "2017-12-14", "2017-12-15", "2017-12-18", "2017-12-20", 
"2017-12-22", "2017-12-24", "2017-12-29", "2017-12-31", "2018-01-02", 
"2018-01-04", "2018-01-09", "2018-01-13", "2018-01-16", "2018-01-17", 
"2018-01-22", "2018-01-25", "2018-01-29", "2018-02-02", "2018-02-03", 
"2018-02-05", "2018-02-06", "2018-02-09", "2018-02-13", "2018-02-16", 
"2018-02-19", "2018-02-24", "2018-02-26", "2018-03-05", "2018-03-08", 
"2018-03-11", "2018-03-14", "2018-03-16", "2018-03-21", "2018-03-26", 
"2018-03-29", "2018-03-30", "2018-03-31", "2018-04-04", "2018-04-05", 
"2018-04-08", "2018-04-12", "2018-04-20", "2018-04-23", "2018-04-26", 
"2018-05-06", "2018-05-10", "2018-05-15", "2018-05-18", "2018-05-22", 
"2018-06-04", "2018-06-08", "2018-06-11", "2018-06-16", "2018-06-17", 
"2018-06-20", "2018-06-22", "2018-06-28", "2018-07-02", "2018-07-04", 
"2018-07-09", "2018-07-17", "2018-07-21", "2018-07-23", "2018-07-24", 
"2018-07-31", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-02", "2018-08-03", "2018-08-06", 
"2018-08-07", "2018-08-08", "2018-08-10", "2018-08-13", "2018-08-14", 
"2018-08-15", "2018-08-17", "2018-08-21", "2018-09-07", "2018-09-11", 
"2018-09-19", "2018-09-21", "2018-09-24", "2018-09-25", "2018-09-26", 
"2018-09-28", "2018-10-02", "2018-10-05", "2018-10-07", "2018-10-10", 
"2018-10-11", "2018-10-12", "2018-10-15", "2018-10-17", "2018-10-19", 
"2018-10-22", "2018-10-23", "2018-10-24", "2018-10-26", "2018-10-28", 
"2018-10-29", "2018-10-30", "2018-10-31", "2018-11-02", "2018-11-05", 
"2018-11-06", "2018-11-07", "2018-11-09", "2018-11-10", "2018-11-11", 
"2018-11-12", "2018-11-13", "2018-11-14", "2018-11-16", "2018-11-19", 
"2018-11-20", "2018-11-21", "2018-11-23", "2018-11-24", "2018-11-26", 
"2018-11-30", "2018-12-02", "2018-12-03", "2018-12-04", "2018-12-05", 
"2018-12-06", "2018-12-07", "2018-12-09", "2018-12-10", "2018-12-11", 
"2018-12-12", "2018-12-16", "2018-12-17", "2018-12-18", "2018-12-19", 
"2018-12-21", "2018-12-24", "2018-12-25", "2018-12-28", "2018-12-30", 
"2018-12-31", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-05", 
"2019-01-06", "2019-01-09", "2019-01-11", "2019-01-14", "2019-01-15", 
"2019-01-16", "2019-01-17", "2019-01-18", "2019-01-21", "2019-01-23", 
"2019-01-26", "2019-01-27", "2019-01-28", "2019-01-29", "2019-01-30", 
"2019-01-31", "2019-02-01", "2019-02-02", "2019-02-04", "2019-02-05", 
"2019-02-06", "2019-02-08", "2019-02-10", "2019-02-11", "2019-02-12", 
"2019-02-13", "2019-02-14", "2019-02-15", "2019-02-17", "2019-02-18", 
"2019-02-19", "2019-02-20", "2019-02-22", "2019-02-24", "2019-02-25", 
"2019-02-26", "2019-02-27", "2019-03-01", "2019-03-02", "2019-03-03", 
"2019-03-04", "2019-03-05", "2019-03-06", "2019-03-08", "2019-03-11", 
"2019-03-12", "2019-03-13", "2019-03-14", "2019-03-15", "2019-03-16", 
"2019-03-18", "2019-03-20", "2019-03-22", "2019-03-24", "2019-03-25", 
"2019-03-26", "2019-03-28", "2019-03-29", "2019-03-30", "2019-04-01", 
"2019-04-02", "2019-04-03", "2019-04-05", "2019-04-07", "2019-04-08", 
"2019-04-09", "2019-04-10", "2019-04-11", "2019-04-12", "2019-04-13", 
"2019-04-14", "2019-04-15", "2019-04-16", "2019-04-17", "2019-04-19", 
"2019-04-20", "2019-04-22", "2019-04-23", "2019-04-24", "2019-04-25", 
"2019-04-26", "2019-04-28", "2019-04-29", "2019-04-30", "2019-05-01", 
"2019-05-02", "2019-05-03", "2019-05-04", "2019-05-05", "2019-05-06", 
"2019-05-07", "2019-05-08", "2019-05-09", "2019-05-10", "2019-05-12", 
"2019-05-13", "2019-05-14", "2019-05-15", "2019-05-16", "2019-05-17", 
"2019-05-18", "2019-05-20", "2019-05-21", "2019-05-22", "2019-05-23", 
"2019-05-24", "2019-05-25", "2019-05-27", "2019-05-28", "2019-05-29", 
"2019-05-31", "2019-06-01", "2019-06-03", "2019-06-04", "2019-06-05", 
"2019-06-07", "2019-06-08", "2019-06-10", "2019-06-11", "2019-06-12", 
"2019-06-13", "2019-06-14", "2019-06-15", "2019-06-17", "2019-06-18", 
"2019-06-19", "2019-06-20", "2019-06-21", "2019-06-22", "2019-06-24", 
"2019-06-25", "2019-06-27", "2019-06-28", "2019-06-30", "2019-07-01", 
"2019-07-02", "2019-07-03", "2019-07-04", "2019-07-05", "2019-07-06", 
"2019-07-07", "2019-07-08", "2019-07-09", "2019-07-10", "2019-07-11", 
"2019-07-12", "2019-07-14", "2019-07-15", "2019-07-16", "2019-07-17", 
"2019-07-19", "2019-07-20", "2019-07-22", "2019-07-23", "2019-07-26", 
"2019-07-27", "2019-07-29", "2019-07-30", "2019-07-31", "2019-08-03", 
"2019-08-05", "2019-08-07", "2019-08-09", "2019-08-10", "2019-08-12", 
"2019-08-15", "2019-08-20", "2019-08-21", "2019-08-26", "2019-08-27", 
"2019-08-29", "2019-08-30", "2019-08-31", "2019-09-02", "2019-09-03", 
"2019-09-05", "2019-09-06", "2019-09-08", "2019-09-09", "2019-09-11", 
"2019-09-12", "2019-09-13", "2019-09-14", "2019-09-16", "2019-09-17", 
"2019-09-18", "2019-09-20", "2019-09-21", "2019-09-25", "2019-09-26", 
"2019-09-30", "2019-10-04", "2019-10-07", "2019-10-09", "2019-10-11", 
"2019-10-12", "2019-10-15", "2019-10-16", "2019-10-17", "2019-10-18", 
"2019-10-21", "2019-10-22", "2019-10-23", "2019-10-24", "2019-10-25", 
"2019-10-27", "2019-10-28", "2019-10-31", "2019-11-01", "2019-11-02", 
"2019-11-04", "2019-11-05", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-08", "2019-11-09", 
"2019-11-11", "2019-11-12", "2019-11-13", "2019-11-14", "2019-11-15", 
"2019-11-18", "2019-11-19", "2019-11-20", "2019-11-21", "2019-11-22", 
"2019-11-23", "2019-11-26", "2019-11-30", "2019-12-01", "2019-12-02", 
"2019-12-03", "2019-12-05", "2019-12-06", "2019-12-07", "2019-12-09", 
"2019-12-11", "2019-12-16", "2019-12-18", "2019-12-20", "2019-12-21", 
"2019-12-25", "2019-12-29", "2019-12-30", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", 
"2020-01-06", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-09", "2020-01-13", "2020-01-14", 
"2020-01-16", "2020-01-17", "2020-01-20", "2020-01-22", "2020-01-25", 
"2020-01-27", "2020-01-28", "2020-01-30", "2020-01-31", "2020-02-01", 
"2020-02-03", "2020-02-10", "2020-02-12", "2020-02-14", "2020-02-20", 
"2020-02-21", "2020-02-22", "2020-02-24", "2020-02-25", "2020-02-26", 
"2020-02-28", "2020-03-02", "2020-03-03", "2020-03-04", "2020-03-05", 
"2020-03-07", "2020-03-09", "2020-03-10", "2020-03-11", "2020-03-12", 
"2020-03-13", "2020-03-16", "2020-03-17", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-21", 
"2020-03-23", "2020-03-28", "2020-03-30", "2020-04-01", "2020-04-04", 
"2020-04-10", "2020-04-13", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-15", "2020-04-16", 
"2020-04-17", "2020-04-21", "2020-04-24", "2020-04-25", "2020-04-27", 
"2020-05-01", "2020-05-02", "2020-05-04", "2020-05-08", "2020-05-11", 
"2020-05-13", "2020-05-15", "2020-05-18", "2020-05-20", "2020-05-23", 
"2020-05-25", "2020-05-27", "2020-06-01", "2020-06-02", "2020-06-03", 
"2020-06-04", "2020-06-05", "2020-06-06", "2020-06-08", "2020-06-09", 
"2020-06-10", "2020-06-12", "2020-06-13", "2020-06-15", "2020-06-17", 
"2020-06-19", "2020-06-20", "2020-06-22", "2020-06-23", "2020-06-24", 
"2020-06-26", "2020-06-27", "2020-06-29", "2020-06-30", "2020-07-01", 
"2020-07-02", "2020-07-03", "2020-07-04", "2020-07-05", "2020-07-06", 
"2020-07-13", "2020-07-15", "2020-07-17", "2020-07-18", "2020-07-20", 
"2020-07-21", "2020-07-31", "2020-08-01", "2020-08-05", "2020-08-11", 
"2020-08-15", "2020-08-19", "2020-08-21", "2020-08-22", "2020-08-24", 
"2020-08-25", "2020-08-26", "2020-08-31", "2020-09-05", "2020-09-07", 
"2020-09-08", "2020-09-10", "2020-09-11", "2020-09-12", "2020-09-13", 
"2020-09-16", "2020-09-18", "2020-09-20", "2020-09-21", "2020-09-22", 
"2020-09-23", "2020-09-24", "2020-09-25", "2020-09-26", "2020-09-28", 
"2020-09-29", "2020-09-30", "2020-10-04", "2020-10-05", "2020-10-06", 
"2020-10-07", "2020-10-09", "2020-10-10", "2020-10-12", "2020-10-13", 
"2020-10-19", "2020-10-23", "2020-10-26", "2020-10-28", "2020-10-30", 
"2020-11-02", "2020-11-07", "2020-11-13", "2020-11-16", "2020-11-17", 
"2020-11-18", "2020-11-20", "2020-11-23", "2020-11-25", "2020-11-28", 
"2020-11-30", "2020-12-01", "2020-12-02", "2020-12-04", "2020-12-05", 
"2020-12-07", "2020-12-08", "2020-12-09", "2020-12-11", "2020-12-12", 
"2020-12-13", "2020-12-14", "2020-12-15", "2020-12-16", "2020-12-17", 
"2020-12-18", "2020-12-19", "2020-12-21", "2020-12-22", "2020-12-25", 
"2020-12-28", "2020-12-29", "2020-12-30", "2021-01-01", "2021-01-04", 
"2021-01-05", "2021-01-06", "2021-01-07", "2021-01-08"), class = "factor"), 
    container_ids = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("GL1", 
    "GL2", "PA1", "PA2", "PA3", "PL1", "PMD1", "REF1", "TEX1"
    ), class = "factor"), fill_level = structure(c(48L, 29L, 
    29L, 70L, 44L, 63L, 45L, 41L, 47L, 35L, 40L, 51L, 33L, 38L, 
    62L, 45L, 35L, 59L, 61L, 41L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
    "4", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
    "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
    "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
    "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", 
    "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", 
    "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", 
    "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", 
    "76", "78", "79", "80", "82", "84", "85", "86", "88", "89", 
    "90", "92", "93", "94", "100"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), groups = structure(list(datum = structure(1:20, .Label = c("2017-01-02", 
"2017-01-04", "2017-01-05", "2017-01-09", "2017-01-12", "2017-01-16", 
"2017-01-19", "2017-01-21", "2017-01-23", "2017-01-26", "2017-01-28", 
"2017-01-30", "2017-02-02", "2017-02-03", "2017-02-06", "2017-02-10", 
"2017-02-13", "2017-02-18", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-23", "2017-02-25", 
"2017-02-27", "2017-03-03", "2017-03-06", "2017-03-13", "2017-03-15", 
"2017-03-17", "2017-03-20", "2017-03-21", "2017-03-27", "2017-03-31", 
"2017-04-03", "2017-04-05", "2017-04-07", "2017-04-10", "2017-04-15", 
"2017-04-16", "2017-04-20", "2017-04-24", "2017-04-25", "2017-04-28", 
"2017-05-01", "2017-05-06", "2017-05-08", "2017-05-11", "2017-05-13", 
"2017-05-15", "2017-05-17", "2017-05-19", "2017-05-22", "2017-05-26", 
"2017-05-31", "2017-06-03", "2017-06-06", "2017-06-08", "2017-06-13", 
"2017-06-23", "2017-06-26", "2017-07-04", "2017-07-11", "2017-07-12", 
"2017-07-15", "2017-07-17", "2017-07-19", "2017-07-28", "2017-07-31", 
"2017-08-03", "2017-08-05", "2017-08-07", "2017-08-10", "2017-08-12", 
"2017-08-15", "2017-08-16", "2017-08-18", "2017-08-21", "2017-08-24", 
"2017-08-25", "2017-08-29", "2017-09-02", "2017-09-05", "2017-09-07", 
"2017-09-12", "2017-09-13", "2017-09-16", "2017-09-18", "2017-09-25", 
"2017-10-06", "2017-10-09", "2017-10-11", "2017-10-13", "2017-10-16", 
"2017-10-17", "2017-10-20", "2017-10-23", "2017-10-25", "2017-10-27", 
"2017-11-02", "2017-11-06", "2017-11-09", "2017-11-11", "2017-11-13", 
"2017-11-15", "2017-11-20", "2017-11-24", "2017-11-27", "2017-11-28", 
"2017-12-07", "2017-12-14", "2017-12-15", "2017-12-18", "2017-12-20", 
"2017-12-22", "2017-12-24", "2017-12-29", "2017-12-31", "2018-01-02", 
"2018-01-04", "2018-01-09", "2018-01-13", "2018-01-16", "2018-01-17", 
"2018-01-22", "2018-01-25", "2018-01-29", "2018-02-02", "2018-02-03", 
"2018-02-05", "2018-02-06", "2018-02-09", "2018-02-13", "2018-02-16", 
"2018-02-19", "2018-02-24", "2018-02-26", "2018-03-05", "2018-03-08", 
"2018-03-11", "2018-03-14", "2018-03-16", "2018-03-21", "2018-03-26", 
"2018-03-29", "2018-03-30", "2018-03-31", "2018-04-04", "2018-04-05", 
"2018-04-08", "2018-04-12", "2018-04-20", "2018-04-23", "2018-04-26", 
"2018-05-06", "2018-05-10", "2018-05-15", "2018-05-18", "2018-05-22", 
"2018-06-04", "2018-06-08", "2018-06-11", "2018-06-16", "2018-06-17", 
"2018-06-20", "2018-06-22", "2018-06-28", "2018-07-02", "2018-07-04", 
"2018-07-09", "2018-07-17", "2018-07-21", "2018-07-23", "2018-07-24", 
"2018-07-31", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-02", "2018-08-03", "2018-08-06", 
"2018-08-07", "2018-08-08", "2018-08-10", "2018-08-13", "2018-08-14", 
"2018-08-15", "2018-08-17", "2018-08-21", "2018-09-07", "2018-09-11", 
"2018-09-19", "2018-09-21", "2018-09-24", "2018-09-25", "2018-09-26", 
"2018-09-28", "2018-10-02", "2018-10-05", "2018-10-07", "2018-10-10", 
"2018-10-11", "2018-10-12", "2018-10-15", "2018-10-17", "2018-10-19", 
"2018-10-22", "2018-10-23", "2018-10-24", "2018-10-26", "2018-10-28", 
"2018-10-29", "2018-10-30", "2018-10-31", "2018-11-02", "2018-11-05", 
"2018-11-06", "2018-11-07", "2018-11-09", "2018-11-10", "2018-11-11", 
"2018-11-12", "2018-11-13", "2018-11-14", "2018-11-16", "2018-11-19", 
"2018-11-20", "2018-11-21", "2018-11-23", "2018-11-24", "2018-11-26", 
"2018-11-30", "2018-12-02", "2018-12-03", "2018-12-04", "2018-12-05", 
"2018-12-06", "2018-12-07", "2018-12-09", "2018-12-10", "2018-12-11", 
"2018-12-12", "2018-12-16", "2018-12-17", "2018-12-18", "2018-12-19", 
"2018-12-21", "2018-12-24", "2018-12-25", "2018-12-28", "2018-12-30", 
"2018-12-31", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-05", 
"2019-01-06", "2019-01-09", "2019-01-11", "2019-01-14", "2019-01-15", 
"2019-01-16", "2019-01-17", "2019-01-18", "2019-01-21", "2019-01-23", 
"2019-01-26", "2019-01-27", "2019-01-28", "2019-01-29", "2019-01-30", 
"2019-01-31", "2019-02-01", "2019-02-02", "2019-02-04", "2019-02-05", 
"2019-02-06", "2019-02-08", "2019-02-10", "2019-02-11", "2019-02-12", 
"2019-02-13", "2019-02-14", "2019-02-15", "2019-02-17", "2019-02-18", 
"2019-02-19", "2019-02-20", "2019-02-22", "2019-02-24", "2019-02-25", 
"2019-02-26", "2019-02-27", "2019-03-01", "2019-03-02", "2019-03-03", 
"2019-03-04", "2019-03-05", "2019-03-06", "2019-03-08", "2019-03-11", 
"2019-03-12", "2019-03-13", "2019-03-14", "2019-03-15", "2019-03-16", 
"2019-03-18", "2019-03-20", "2019-03-22", "2019-03-24", "2019-03-25", 
"2019-03-26", "2019-03-28", "2019-03-29", "2019-03-30", "2019-04-01", 
"2019-04-02", "2019-04-03", "2019-04-05", "2019-04-07", "2019-04-08", 
"2019-04-09", "2019-04-10", "2019-04-11", "2019-04-12", "2019-04-13", 
"2019-04-14", "2019-04-15", "2019-04-16", "2019-04-17", "2019-04-19", 
"2019-04-20", "2019-04-22", "2019-04-23", "2019-04-24", "2019-04-25", 
"2019-04-26", "2019-04-28", "2019-04-29", "2019-04-30", "2019-05-01", 
"2019-05-02", "2019-05-03", "2019-05-04", "2019-05-05", "2019-05-06", 
"2019-05-07", "2019-05-08", "2019-05-09", "2019-05-10", "2019-05-12", 
"2019-05-13", "2019-05-14", "2019-05-15", "2019-05-16", "2019-05-17", 
"2019-05-18", "2019-05-20", "2019-05-21", "2019-05-22", "2019-05-23", 
"2019-05-24", "2019-05-25", "2019-05-27", "2019-05-28", "2019-05-29", 
"2019-05-31", "2019-06-01", "2019-06-03", "2019-06-04", "2019-06-05", 
"2019-06-07", "2019-06-08", "2019-06-10", "2019-06-11", "2019-06-12", 
"2019-06-13", "2019-06-14", "2019-06-15", "2019-06-17", "2019-06-18", 
"2019-06-19", "2019-06-20", "2019-06-21", "2019-06-22", "2019-06-24", 
"2019-06-25", "2019-06-27", "2019-06-28", "2019-06-30", "2019-07-01", 
"2019-07-02", "2019-07-03", "2019-07-04", "2019-07-05", "2019-07-06", 
"2019-07-07", "2019-07-08", "2019-07-09", "2019-07-10", "2019-07-11", 
"2019-07-12", "2019-07-14", "2019-07-15", "2019-07-16", "2019-07-17", 
"2019-07-19", "2019-07-20", "2019-07-22", "2019-07-23", "2019-07-26", 
"2019-07-27", "2019-07-29", "2019-07-30", "2019-07-31", "2019-08-03", 
"2019-08-05", "2019-08-07", "2019-08-09", "2019-08-10", "2019-08-12", 
"2019-08-15", "2019-08-20", "2019-08-21", "2019-08-26", "2019-08-27", 
"2019-08-29", "2019-08-30", "2019-08-31", "2019-09-02", "2019-09-03", 
"2019-09-05", "2019-09-06", "2019-09-08", "2019-09-09", "2019-09-11", 
"2019-09-12", "2019-09-13", "2019-09-14", "2019-09-16", "2019-09-17", 
"2019-09-18", "2019-09-20", "2019-09-21", "2019-09-25", "2019-09-26", 
"2019-09-30", "2019-10-04", "2019-10-07", "2019-10-09", "2019-10-11", 
"2019-10-12", "2019-10-15", "2019-10-16", "2019-10-17", "2019-10-18", 
"2019-10-21", "2019-10-22", "2019-10-23", "2019-10-24", "2019-10-25", 
"2019-10-27", "2019-10-28", "2019-10-31", "2019-11-01", "2019-11-02", 
"2019-11-04", "2019-11-05", "2019-11-06", "2019-11-08", "2019-11-09", 
"2019-11-11", "2019-11-12", "2019-11-13", "2019-11-14", "2019-11-15", 
"2019-11-18", "2019-11-19", "2019-11-20", "2019-11-21", "2019-11-22", 
"2019-11-23", "2019-11-26", "2019-11-30", "2019-12-01", "2019-12-02", 
"2019-12-03", "2019-12-05", "2019-12-06", "2019-12-07", "2019-12-09", 
"2019-12-11", "2019-12-16", "2019-12-18", "2019-12-20", "2019-12-21", 
"2019-12-25", "2019-12-29", "2019-12-30", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", 
"2020-01-06", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-09", "2020-01-13", "2020-01-14", 
"2020-01-16", "2020-01-17", "2020-01-20", "2020-01-22", "2020-01-25", 
"2020-01-27", "2020-01-28", "2020-01-30", "2020-01-31", "2020-02-01", 
"2020-02-03", "2020-02-10", "2020-02-12", "2020-02-14", "2020-02-20", 
"2020-02-21", "2020-02-22", "2020-02-24", "2020-02-25", "2020-02-26", 
"2020-02-28", "2020-03-02", "2020-03-03", "2020-03-04", "2020-03-05", 
"2020-03-07", "2020-03-09", "2020-03-10", "2020-03-11", "2020-03-12", 
"2020-03-13", "2020-03-16", "2020-03-17", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-21", 
"2020-03-23", "2020-03-28", "2020-03-30", "2020-04-01", "2020-04-04", 
"2020-04-10", "2020-04-13", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-15", "2020-04-16", 
"2020-04-17", "2020-04-21", "2020-04-24", "2020-04-25", "2020-04-27", 
"2020-05-01", "2020-05-02", "2020-05-04", "2020-05-08", "2020-05-11", 
"2020-05-13", "2020-05-15", "2020-05-18", "2020-05-20", "2020-05-23", 
"2020-05-25", "2020-05-27", "2020-06-01", "2020-06-02", "2020-06-03", 
"2020-06-04", "2020-06-05", "2020-06-06", "2020-06-08", "2020-06-09", 
"2020-06-10", "2020-06-12", "2020-06-13", "2020-06-15", "2020-06-17", 
"2020-06-19", "2020-06-20", "2020-06-22", "2020-06-23", "2020-06-24", 
"2020-06-26", "2020-06-27", "2020-06-29", "2020-06-30", "2020-07-01", 
"2020-07-02", "2020-07-03", "2020-07-04", "2020-07-05", "2020-07-06", 
"2020-07-13", "2020-07-15", "2020-07-17", "2020-07-18", "2020-07-20", 
"2020-07-21", "2020-07-31", "2020-08-01", "2020-08-05", "2020-08-11", 
"2020-08-15", "2020-08-19", "2020-08-21", "2020-08-22", "2020-08-24", 
"2020-08-25", "2020-08-26", "2020-08-31", "2020-09-05", "2020-09-07", 
"2020-09-08", "2020-09-10", "2020-09-11", "2020-09-12", "2020-09-13", 
"2020-09-16", "2020-09-18", "2020-09-20", "2020-09-21", "2020-09-22", 
"2020-09-23", "2020-09-24", "2020-09-25", "2020-09-26", "2020-09-28", 
"2020-09-29", "2020-09-30", "2020-10-04", "2020-10-05", "2020-10-06", 
"2020-10-07", "2020-10-09", "2020-10-10", "2020-10-12", "2020-10-13", 
"2020-10-19", "2020-10-23", "2020-10-26", "2020-10-28", "2020-10-30", 
"2020-11-02", "2020-11-07", "2020-11-13", "2020-11-16", "2020-11-17", 
"2020-11-18", "2020-11-20", "2020-11-23", "2020-11-25", "2020-11-28", 
"2020-11-30", "2020-12-01", "2020-12-02", "2020-12-04", "2020-12-05", 
"2020-12-07", "2020-12-08", "2020-12-09", "2020-12-11", "2020-12-12", 
"2020-12-13", "2020-12-14", "2020-12-15", "2020-12-16", "2020-12-17", 
"2020-12-18", "2020-12-19", "2020-12-21", "2020-12-22", "2020-12-25", 
"2020-12-28", "2020-12-29", "2020-12-30", "2021-01-01", "2021-01-04", 
"2021-01-05", "2021-01-06", "2021-01-07", "2021-01-08"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
        10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you provide a `minimal` reproducable example? There is really a lot of code there. If you gave us just a small ready-to-copy dataframe, the desired output, and the exact problem you encounter, it would be easier for us to help you. In the current form, there is just a lot of code and it is unclear where/what your problem is.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example here how to make a great reproducible example in R.

Comment: I've changed the question. Maybe it is more clear now? @coffeinjunky

Comment: That's better, but I still can't copy-paste your data into my R console to see what might be going wrong. If you copy the output of `dput(your_data_frame)`, or if that is too large, `dput(head(your_data_frame, 20))`, it would be easier.

Comment: I copied the output in the question. i used the head command otherwise it would be to large @coffeinjunky

Comment: Sorry, should have anticipated that, but your example data only contains one `container_id`, so I can't reproduce any error. Is it correct that `fill_level` is the dependent variable and you want to run a linear regression with container ID and date as explanatory variables, right?

Comment: So, the regression will be `fill_level ~ container_id_dummies + date_dummies`, or will it be `fill_level ~ container_id_dummies`?

Comment: Fill_level is our dependent variable and we only want to dummify the container_ids. the independent variables are date and container_id_dummies @coffeinjunky

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you do the cbind() wrongly, it should be `container_group[,c(1,3)]` instead of `container_group[c(1,3)]`:

```
da = data.frame(datum = c("2017-04-20","2019-01-11","2019-05-03"),container_ids = c("REF1","GL1","PA1"),fill_level = c(100,94,93))
dummy_container_ids <- dummy(da$container_ids, sep="_")

cbind(container_group[,c(1,3)],dummy_container_ids)
       datum fill_level container_ids_GL1 container_ids_PA1 container_ids_REF1
1 2017-04-20        100                 0                 0                  1
2 2019-01-11         94                 1                 0                  0
3 2019-05-03         93                 0                 1                  0
```